# Not receiving data from firebase?

Tags: firebase, url, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to load data from Firebase which I have been able to do with the following code in the past however I added an additional child and as a result the following code now doesn't work. and I am lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

image is a UIImageView

[image: Here is the image of my firebase]

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let content2 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["imageWebsite"] as? String ?? ""
            let content3 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["infoWebsite"] as? String ?? ""

            self.imgURL = content2
            self.infoURL = content3

        })


        print(imgURL)
        image.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: imgURL)
```

Comment: What do you get when you print out your snapshot inside the `with` block?

Comment: Do you "Allow Arbitrary Loads" in your "App Transport Security Settings" ?

Comment: I do have all security transport settings set to allow

Comment: Interesting, it is pulling the correct url, i might try putting the     `setImageFromURL` func inside the `with` block

Comment: That worked! Thank you, i thought it was todo with the child being incorrectly referenced or something, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the `setImageFromURL` func in the database query it executes the code prior to completing the query ensuring the `objects` are loaded.

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        databaseRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {
            snapshot in

            let content2 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["imageWebsite4"] as? String ?? ""
            let content3 = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["infoWebsite4"] as? String ?? ""

            self.imgURL = content2
            self.infoURL = content3
            print(content2)

            print(self.imgURL)
            self.image.setImageFromURl(stringImageUrl: self.imgURL)


        })
```